# how to mention dynamic query params in swagger with name constraints like 'column_0' , 'column_1' ...... upto 'column_N' , where N being any number

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have developed a get API that takes an array in one of queryParams called "reportType", the thing is that i have another queryParam (also an array) associated with each array element, so let's say if i have reportType param as `['a','b','c']`, then i will have 3 queryParams :-

```
   column_0 : [...some_elements] 
   column_1 : [...some_elements] 
   column_2 : [...some_elements]
```

`column_1`  can be absent if not needed. How do i mention it in swagger ?

Comment: sounds like you should be using a requestBody instead of query parameters. Then you can define a schema to capture the conditions required for your response.